# Add arguments to get request

Tags: solidity, chainlink, external-api

I'm trying to make a get request using the chainlink node. I'm following this tutorial [this tutorial](https://docs.chain.link/docs/make-a-http-get-request/) but the problem is that this is sending a request to this specific URL `https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/pricemultifull?fsyms=ETH&tsyms=USD`.

I, on the other hand, want to send a request that will change according to what happens inside the smart contract, for example, call `https://myapi.com/?foo=0` or `https://myapi.com/?foo=1` depending on specific conditions.

My solution so far has been to create a `_buildRequestURI` function that looks something like this:

```
function _buildRequestURI(Foo memory foo) public pure returns (string memory) {
    return string(abi.encodePacked(
      BASE_URI,
      "foo=", foo.foo
    ));
  }
```

Where Foo is my struct and `foo.foo` is an enum but for some reason `foo.foo` is not showing up on my final string. What am I doing wrong? Is there a better way to build this URL? Or better yet, add arguments to my get request? I'm using solidity 0.8.7

Answer (score 2):

The current solution I found was to build a `mapping(Foo => string)` and then replace the code with:

```
function _buildRequestURI(Foo memory foo) public pure returns (string memory) {
    return string(abi.encodePacked(
      BASE_URI,
      "foo=", myMapping[foo.foo]
    ));
  }
```

Comment: I'd say it is better to use functions like `uint2str` and `strConcat`  from this question https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/99538/making-get-request-with-chainlink-using-dynamic-url-params